I am trying to add plaid. It not working "native model plaid android tried to override com.react library.plaidmodle" in android
I have tried to implement the plaid in Android. Its not working.
The package I have used is react-native-plaid-link-sdk
I have followed this document.
I have implemeted the line in the MainApplication.java file
    @Override
    protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
      List<ReactPackage> packages = new PackageList(this).getPackages();
      packages.add(new PlaidPackage());
      return packages;
    }

I am getting the error like:


Maybe your PlaidAndroid module has been auto-linking after you install react-native-plaid-link-sdk.
Try revert your change in MainApplication.java (remove       packages.add(new PlaidPackage()); ) and run your app again.

I have tried that, but plaid is not opening. While I am trying to open its loading, the screen is ending, and printing the result in the onEnd property.
